# Irreducible representations and subrepresentations of the regular representation

Tags: proof-explanation, representation-theory

I am currently taking a first course in representation theory and there is a theorem that I am having some trouble with, having to do with the number of isomorphism classes of irreducible representations, on the proof of which I was hoping I could get some clarification. I would like to note that there have been similar questions posted, but the answers I've found there used character theory or the group algebra, which the proof in our course does not use.

The situation is as follows: one has a finite group $G$, an irreducible representation $\rho:G\to\text{GL}(V)$ and the regular representation on the space of functions $\mathbb K^G$. The first thing one does is show that $V$ is isomorphic to a subrepresentation of $\mathbb K^G$. This is done explicitly, by showing that each element $\alpha$ of the dual space $V^*$ defines a homomorphism of representations $T_\alpha:V\to\mathbb K^G$, such that $T_\alpha(v)(g)=\alpha(\rho(g^{-1})v)$. If I've understood this correctly, this part is simply a matter of unwinding definitions and using Schur's lemma: $V$ is irreducible, hence for $\alpha\neq0$ the kernel of $T_\alpha$ is zero (the alternative is $V$ itself, but since $\alpha\neq0,\exists x\neq0:\alpha(x)\neq0$ and one can take $v=\rho(g)x$, i.e. the kernel can't be all of $V$, so it is $0$), that is $T_\alpha$ is an isomorphism onto its image, a subrepresentation of $\mathbb K^G$. My first question is this makes $T_\alpha(V)$ irreducible, since $T_\alpha$ is injective, right? $V$ can't be isomorphic to a reducible subrepresentation of $\mathbb K^G$, can it?

Next, one constructs inductively a chain of subrepresentations $0=U_0\subset U_1\subset\cdots\subset U_{n-1}\subset U_n=\mathbb K^G$ such that each $U_{j}\subset U_{j+1}$ is minimal, i.e. such that each $U_{j+1}/U_j$ is irreducible. This chain obviously cannot be longer than $\dim\mathbb K^G=|G|$. Next, one claims that the image of $V$ is placed somewhere between two successive elements, i.e. $\exists j$ such that $U_j\subsetneq T_\alpha(V)\subset U_{j+1}$. Why should this hold? Might the image of $V$ not get "spread around" in some way? Why does it have to be placed precisely between two links in this chain? Why should $U_j$ be a proper subset of $T_\alpha(V)$?

Next one composes $T_\alpha$ with the projection $\pi:U_{j+1}\to U_{j+1}/U_j$ and gets a homomorphism of representations $\pi\circ T_\alpha:V\to U_{j+1}/U_j$, that is $\neq0$, since $U_j\subsetneq T_\alpha(V)$ (again, why should this proper inclusion hold?), hence by Schur's lemma it is an isomorphism, that is, every irreducible representation $V$ is isomorphic to some quotient $U_{j+1}/U_j$. There are at most $\dim\mathbb K^G$ of these, hence there are at most $|G|$ isomorphism classes of irreducible representations.

As one can see from what I've written, my issue mainly lies with the second paragraph, the rest of the theorem follows pretty much directly from it. Thank you for reading.

Comment: You're right, the image of $V$ might not be placed in a nice position in the chain - but if you are warned about the image of $V$ up-front, it is always possible to construct the chain so that it gets placed between two successive elements.

Comment: How exactly would one do this? The proof in our lecture does not mention, it simply states that such a flag can be constructed. Is the image of $V$ an irreduciblre subrepresentation of $\mathbb{K}^G$? Does it being placed between two subrepresentations not imply that it is reducible?